# Azure shared storage for application

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Working in IaaS environment in AZURE and need to create a shared file for applications that will be sharing the same files uploaded by end users.  The file share needs to be scene on various servers and appear as a fixed drive letter or mount point.  Already created a Storage account and a file share in azure but can not overcome the issue that the mapped drive is associated with a users profile.
Was wondering if any has come up with a solution. ... I'm the system administrator assigned to this task and can do things in powershell or pass code information to developers for their review.

Comment: Have you considered blob storage?

Comment: `mapped drive is associated with a users profile`. Does it means that each user has a mapped file share directory according to user name ? If yes, we need to create a different file share directory for each user. More information about mount the file share please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share)

Answer (score 0):

Did not resolve issue, developers are going to use Blog storage.

The trick with this was getting the application to see the drive letter. For us having a local user run as a service with the associated Azure file share mapping might have worked

NOTE to map the azure drive a use would need the Azure Storage account and Key generated for that account to access it.